# how to forward/redirect ports using docker ipvlan network

Tags: docker, networking, iptables, docker-network

**Question**: How can I redirect of forward port 80 to port 8080 on the same specific IP address using docker's ipvlan networking?

**Situation**: I've created a docker network by issuing the command

```
docker network create -d ipvlan --subnet=192.168.0.1/22 --gateway=192.168.0.1 \
-o ipvlan_mode=l2 -o parent=enp8s0 my_network
```

My interface `enp8s0` is on the same subnet, same gateway.

I have then created a docker container that has a service that exposes port `8080`, by issuing the following:

```
docker run --detach --restart=unless-stopped \
--network=my_network \
--ip=192.168.2.10 \
--hostname my_service \
--name my_service \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 80:8080 \
my_service:latest
```

I can successfully reach the service on `http://192.168.2.10:8080`.

The problem: I can't reach the service on port `80`. Port `8080` works fine. In this situation is impractical for me to change the internal service configuration as I need *both* ports `80` and `8080` to have connectivity and that would require a lot of code rewriting (and I have other services that I need to do the same forwarding, to different ports).

I've tried, on the host, to use a port forwarding using iptables, by issuing the command `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.2.10 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.10:8080`, but it does not work. Also, I can't see that the IP `.2.10` is assigned to anything on the host.

If it helps, here are some outputs:

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:2e:99:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.194/22 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global dynamic enp8s0
       valid_lft 70764sec preferred_lft 70764sec
    inet6 2607:fea8:2d40:611:b62e:99ff:fe38:7bdf/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 595sec preferred_lft 595sec
    inet6 fe80::b62e:99ff:fe38:7bdf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:4f:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:4fff:feee:4f22/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN

# iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.2.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.10:8080
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
```

Thank you!